# How to dynamically display data from a model using a button in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to load data from a model dynamically, the issue I am having is that I am unable to get the data dynamically, for example this is the model:

```py
class mentee(models.Model):
    application_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    major = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class_standing = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    student_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    profile_pic = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    linkedin = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    github = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    resume = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    area_of_concentration = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    roles_of_interest = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    meet_in_person = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    preferred_years_of_experience = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    organization_of_interest = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    area_of_expertise = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    skills_desired = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100)))
    gender_preference = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    time_preference = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location_preference = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

In this function I am trying invoke is this

```py
    def showprofile(full_name):
       mentee_data = mentee.objects.filter(full_name="Katha Benterman")
       return mentee_data.values()
```

What this should do is that it should show the data in a bootstrap model which is set in the HTML like this:

```html
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Profile</button></td>
             <!-- Modal -->
             <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    {% for profile in show_profile %}
                        {{ profile.full_name }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.email }}
                    </br>

                        {{ profile.phone }}
                    </br>

                        {{ profile.bio }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.gender }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.objectives }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.years_of_experience }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.university }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.graduation_year }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.major }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.class_standing }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.city }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.country }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.student_type }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.profile_pic }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.linkedin }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.GitHub }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.website }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.resume }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.area_of_concentration }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.roles_of_interest }}
                    </br>
                        {{ profile.skills_desired }}
                    </br>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

The issue is when I statically specify a name from the full_name it will load up the data, but when I try to do it dynamically it doesn't show anything at all whatsoever, I think it may be an issue with my function and my button. Any help would be greatly appricated!

Here is the views file:

```py
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = mentee.objects.all()
        profiles = mentee.showprofile(mentee.full_name)

        mentee_data = {
            "full_name": data,
            "email": data,
            "email": data,
            "phone" : data,
            "bio" : data,
            "gender" : data,
            "objectives" : data,
            "years_of_experience" : data,
            "university" : data,
            "graduation_year" : data,
            "major" : data,
            "class_standing" : data,
            "city" : data,
            "country" : data,
            "student_type" : data,
            "profile_pic" : data,
            "linkedin" : data,
            "GitHub" : data,
            "website" : data,
            "resume" : data,
            "area_of_concentration" : data,
            "roles_of_interest" : data,
            "skills_desired": data,
            "show_profile": profiles

        }

        return render(request, 'main/index.html', mentee_data)
```

Comment: What do you mean, "do it dynamically"? Show the code that is doing the dynamic thing. Is it some kind of Ajax?

Comment: The are tables in a postgressql database, the code that is is supposed to do it dynamically is the function that is specified `showprofile` which is filtering out the users with a full_name, in this case it is filtering out the person `Katha Benterman`. When in the modal I am only able to to show data to that person, because I have a show profile button on each person i want to show that data for those each persons not just the person that is manually filtered out

Comment: Yes but how do you want to choose that name? Where is the input coming from?

Comment: That is coming from the column that is in the postgresql database that is populated with test data. Assuming I am understanding the question

Comment: No that wasn't at all what I asked. What will the user do to specify that they want to see the details for a specific user? How will that information get to the Django view?

Comment: In the Django view there is a variable profile, which is being passed as a context as it is being passed as a context a user would be able to click the show profile button and then in that button a modal will open up in the modal all the information of the user will be shown

Comment: `data = mentee.objects.all()` - usage of this `data` is completely wrong.

Comment: But *until you show the code* for that button - both what displays it, and what is triggered when you click it - we cannot help you.

Comment: There are so many mistakes (python mistakes) in your code, I wouldn't know where to start. You should take some time to learn python first (not Django), read a book, go through a course/tutorial, so you understand what the types of your variables are and how to call functions/methods. Now things like `mentee.showprofile(mentee.full_name)` don't make any sense (`mentee` is a class, not an instance) nor does `data.full_name` (data is  QuerySet or a list)...